# Is there a common name for this design esthetic?

Tags: style-identification

I've lately found some of the following designs and really like the esthetic of them.
Sadly I can't find more inspiration of those to allow me to create me own design.
I would describe the design in question like this:

- mostly monochrome black/white or muted colors
- "epaper" design
- thin lines
- retro futuristic

The design in question can be seen in the following examples:

- https://www.behance.net/gallery/168885893/James-Webb-Retro-Sci-fi-Website
- https://www.behance.net/gallery/65772053/Dune

Do you know how this esthetic is called or where I can find more?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Not everything has a specific name.  You can just use words to describe it.

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that not every style has a name, those (especially the Dune one) are probably best classified as *Vector Graphic*. While this term has mostly been taken over by the meaning *vector format/storage* it was originally used as a term to describe CRT graphic displays which did not use the traditional scanline/raster.

try searching "vector graphic game" (battlezone, star wars, tempest) and/or "vector monitor"

Answer (score 0):

"Monochrome" + "thin lines" might be pretty similar to **blueprints** and **technical drawings**. Neither is exactly "art," but rather both are highly-disciplined visual communication systems. The "disciplined" part makes them easy to riff on aesthetically.

"Retro futuristic" + "thin lines" remind me of **Star Trek TNG computer graphics**. Those were created from scratch for the show and were pretty original at the time. I don’t see many riffs on the aesthetic, but the show’s screen designers put a surprising amount of thought into it, and it’s generally easy to find Trek-inspired stuff.

The James Webb project you referenced has some strong **Brutalist** elements: the monospaced font with exaggerated ink traps, the minimalistic color palette (by which I mean *few*, rather than *muted*), and explicitly outlined borders. I would call the rounded corners more Humanist than Brutalist, but they also fit quite comfortably in the "retro" category.

"Monochrome" + "e-ink" also reminds me of **pen-and-ink illustrations**, like the kind you might see in old-fashioned kids' novels.

For more line-based geometric decoration, try **cyberpunk** or **Art Deco lithography**, or maybe just **engraving design**.

But if you’re honing in on a truly unusual aesthetic, **explore by doing.**